# Font size for different size and dpi devices in smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I am developing an mobile app which should support for all type of device sizes and dpi's. 
Is there any short-way or formula that i can implement for font sizes basing on dpi value of the device?
Can any one suggest whats the best way to implement font sizes for all my controls in Smartface App Studio to support all type of devices!

Answer (score 0):

You should check this link about images : http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/anatomy-project/#images

There is no way to make it look good for all devices by using only one folder. Because different devices have different resolutions, icons should be added to the related folder.

For iOS, there is only one folder. You should use original icons, lets say it is myicon.png, also you should use 2 times the original icon(make it 2 times larger) and add it too into the same folder and name it as myicon@2x.png.
That is all for iOS.

But for Android, there are more different resolutions. You should find the correct folder for your device from the link. I can simply suggest you to keep in mind that, your original icon should be placed under mdpi folder, you should use 1.5 times original in hdpi folder and you should use 2 times the original icon for xhdpi folder.

Comment: Thanks merve. This will help me in setting images in app. But, i need also on font sizes. Basing on dpi, the fonts are getting smaller and larger. How can make them constant in all dpi's?